# Home NAS device infected with virus (probably botnet)

Tags: linux, embedded, nas

I have Zyxel NSA325-v2 NAS at home and lately is started to upload enourmous amount of data so I checked top via it's busy box interface and I found some weird proccesses taking all CPU and upload. So it looks like it has been infected with some botnet virus. The problem is I have limited access because of busybox telnet interface I am able to login as root but I cannot install any tools.

When i print info about the weird process:

```
    ~ # lsof -p 21967
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody  cwd    DIR       0,1        0         1 /
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody  rtd    DIR       0,1        0         1 /
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody  txt    REG       0,1    92284 188725930 /tmp/putin/ns_ntpdd.arm7 (deleted)
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody    0u  IPv4 204479590      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.10:4934->random.url.com:domain (ESTABLISHED)
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody    3w  FIFO       0,5      0t0 188723065 pipe
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody    4u  IPv4 188726953      0t0       TCP localhost.localdomain:34842 (LISTEN)
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody    5w   CHR      4,64      0t0       325 /dev/ttyS0
w0wfhej11 21967 nobody   16r  FIFO       0,5      0t0 188723066 pipe
```

How to remove this virus ?

Comment: Without more information I don't think we can help you. A straight `kill 21967` will obviously get rid of this particular instance. Is your NAS exposed to the internet? If so then it is less likely that your NAS is permanently infected, and an update of the NAS firmware might fix your box.

Comment: Have you tried a re-boot?